# Eigen: Divide each row by last row

Tags: c++, eigen, eigen3

I can't quite figure out the syntax for this when using Eigen's `rowwise` operations...

I have an Eigen matrix, and I want to divide each row by the last row. So if we started with a matrix

```
r = [ 0, 1
      2, 3 
      4, 5 ]
```

then after this transform, I want to have

```
r = [  0, .2
      .5, .6
       1,  1 ]
```

Preferably the operation would happen in place, overwriting `r`. Furthermore, I will not be using the values in the last row, so it doesn't matter if the last row is actually 1's after the transform.

Here are some syntaxes I have tried that do not compile:

```
r.rowwise() = (r.array().rowwise() / r.bottomRows(1).array()).eval();
r.rowwise() = (r.rowwise().array() / r.bottomRows(1).array()).eval();
r.rowwise() /= r.bottomRows(1).array();
r = r.rowwise().cwiseQuotient(rrr);
```

This plain old for-loop version works

```
int last_row = r.rows() - 1;
for (int row = 0; row < last_row; ++row) {
    r.row(row).array() /= r.row(last_row).array();
}
```

However, everywhere I turn, people are advocating using the `rowwise` or `colwise` operations. I can't get this to work with that syntax. Is there a nice concise form of what I want to do using the `rowwise` operator?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To complete the self-answer, in case you don't need the last row, you can use [hnormalized](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__Geometry__Module.html#ga1f220045efa302626c287088b63b6ba9):

```
result = r.colwise().hnormalized()
```

and with Eigen trunk you can also write:

```
using namespace Eigen::placeholders::last;
r.array().rowwise() /= r.row(last).array();
```

Comment: I am surprised there is not a "in place" version of `hnormalized()`.

Answer (score 2):

Of course, I finally find the correct syntax after posting...

```
int last_row = r.rows() - 1;
r.array().rowwise() /= r.row(last_row).array();
```

For some reason, using `bottomRows` here leads to a compilation error. That is, the following does not compile

```
r.array().rowwise() /= r.bottomRows(1).array();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you *do* need the last row, there's `r.colwise().hnormalized().colwise().homogeneous()`.

I agree, though, that this seems like it'd be useful to have an in-place method to do this.