# Eigen 3 Square Array Divided by Column Array

Tags: c++, eigen, eigen3

I want to divide each row of a square array(`b`) by the transpose of a column array (`a`).

Test code is also at [godbolt.org](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,source:'%23include+%3CEigen/Eigen%3E%0A%23include+%3Ciostream%3E%0Ausing+namespace+Eigen%3B%0A%0Aint+main()+%7B%0A++++ArrayXXf+a(3,+1)%3B%0A++++a+%3C%3C+2,+2,+2%3B%0A++++ArrayXXf+b(3,+3)%3B%0A++++b+%3C%3C+1,+2,+3,+4,+5,+6,+7,+8,+9%3B%0A++++std::cout+%3C%3C+a+%3C%3C+%22%5Cn%22%3B%0A++++std::cout+%3C%3C+b+%3C%3C+%22%5Cn%22%3B%0A++++b.rowwise()+/%3D+a.transpose()%3B%0A++++std::cout+%3C%3C+b+%3C%3C+%22%5Cn%22%3B%0A%7D'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:33.333333333333336,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g82,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'0',trim:'1'),lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!((name:eigen,ver:trunk)),options:'',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+gcc+8.2+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),k:33.333333333333336,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:output,i:(compiler:1,editor:1,wrap:'1'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'%231+with+x86-64+gcc+8.2',t:'0')),k:33.33333333333333,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4), which has an installation of the eigen 3 library.

Expected Result:

```
// before (a)
2
2
2
// before (b)
2 2 2
4 4 4
6 6 6
// after
1 1 1
2 2 2
3 3 3
```

Test:

```
#include <Eigen/Eigen>
#include <iostream>
using namespace Eigen;

int main() {
    ArrayXXf a(3, 1);
    a << 2, 2, 2;
    ArrayXXf b(3, 3);
    b << 2, 2, 2, 4, 4, 4, 6, 6, 6;
    std::cout << a << "\n";
    std::cout << b << "\n";
    b.rowwise() /= a.transpose();
    std::cout << b << "\n";
}
```

Compilation Error

```
...
error: static assertion failed: YOU_TRIED_CALLING_A_VECTOR_METHOD_ON_A_MATRIX
...
```

Related Question:

[Eigen: Divide each row by last row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48930949/eigen-divide-each-row-by-last-row)

The accepted answer is using rowwise on Eigen matrices converted to Eigen arrays. I just don't get why it doesn't work in my case...

Comment: I can do this with one or two for loops... But what went wrong here??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The assertion tells you that you are using a matrix (aka 2D array), whereas a compile-time vector (aka 1D array) is expected. So the solution is to define `a` as a compile-time 1D array:

```
ArrayXf a(3);
```

You can also see this operation in terms of standard linear algebra:

```
VectorXd a(3);
MatrixXd b(3,3);
b = b * a.asDiagonal().inverse();
```